# Try to write into syslog

Tags: python, linux, syslog

I am working in linux and the process rsyslogd is listening to port 514.
The following code can't write into /var/log/syslog.
Is anybody know what is the problem?

```
import logging
import logging.handlers


root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(config.get_value("log_level"))
syslog_hdlr = SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log', facility=SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON)
syslog_hdlr.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)s: %(levelname)s %(message)s')
syslog_hdlr.setFormatter(formatter)
root_logger.addHandler(syslog_hdlr)

logger = logging.getLogger("imapcd.daemon")
logger.debug('test')
```

Comment: Hi, what's the error? Also, if this is just a snippet, I cannot see where `config` originates from.

Comment: If you use the syslog module (`from syslog import syslog; syslog("MY MESSAGE")`) you get anything?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This code works fine in my system if I make some changes:

```
import logging.handlers as sh
syslog_hdlr = sh.SysLogHandler(address='/dev/log', facility=sh.SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON)
```

and

```
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

So check the logging level  you are getting from `config` is not more restrictive than `DEBUG` (ex: if it is set to `INFO` no debug messages are printed).

If you still don't see anything on syslog try to use the `syslog` module and see if you get anything from there:

```
import syslog
syslog.syslog(syslog.LOG_ERR, "MY MESSAGE")
```

Comment: Ty. How I can send it to remote server?
Where should I configure the IP?

Comment: @roihatam I hadn't tried it, but `SyslogHandler` accepts an (address, port) tuple as argument. See [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.handlers.html#sysloghandler).

Comment: OK, I have already found it.  syslog_hdlr = SysLogHandler(address=('192.168.1.101', 514), facility=SysLogHandler.LOG_DAEMON)

Comment: Still relevant as of 2017, used the last form (the simplest one), with success...thanks!